# Cheap but programming rich phone?

Tags: android, mobile, java-me, symbian

You think to yourself: what this question has to do with programming? Let me explain.

I had a SE K770i and tried to write a software on it that records sound and sends it to the server. And it occurred that the development framework on this phone limits and makes it hard to send big chunks of data.

So now i use older phone. But would like to start write some kicking bad-asses software for some new technology. So i figured out i ask you guys what is the most programmer-friendly hi-tech phone right now that is cheap and popular.

What the phone needs to have:

- good software development documentation
- must be cheap
- must have recording, touch screen, video and sending data via internet support
- must have nice access to all this resources from source code
- must be popular

And it should NOT be Apple, because i can't effort 200 dollars a year to write some apps and don't like the whole verification think.

What hi-tech, cheap phone is a right way for a mobile developer these days?

Comment: Instead of having to write separate apps for all the various mobile operating systems, have you considered writing a web app that supports any old phone with a browser? Look at all the fancy stuff they have on the way in [jQueryMobile](http://jquerymobile.com/), for example.

Comment: @DOK i don't think it has support for the things i wrote about. I need one strong software development platform for one phone i will buy. Don't need so much like broad perspective.

Comment: Cheap - not more than 500 dollars

Comment: I'm not sure the technology would be so difficult for a web app. Think about it: what do you call it when you record a message and send it to a server? Voice mail! How hard is that? And for video, there's already Skype. BTW, I wouldn't call a $500 phone "cheap".

Comment: @DOK Using voice mail you depend on very obsolete technology and you have less control, higher spread of system and more risk of failures. Video: do mobile Skype have a API to control it and embed in my app? I suppose not. And last question: is $500 cheap? In the range of new phones it's cheap. You can buy phones that are for 1000 $ now.

Comment: Check it out. "At [Skype developer](http://developer.skype.com/), you'll find everything you need to build Skype into your own hardware and software." Just so you're aware that you may be trying to reinvent the wheel. And yes, $500 is a lot of money for anything. I would consider $100 a cheap phone.

Comment: @DOK as i can see it, it's invite beta stage now and it's not for mobiles. So it's not so good and you can't use it with jQueryMobile. But interesting to keep an eye on it- thx. And FYI: pls stop persuading, it's going no where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As HW goes, perhaps this one which is a cheep android phone which received a lot of positive acclaim http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZTE_Blade.

Comment: +1 definitely what comes to mind when looking for a cheap Android development phone. Just make sure to get a second-gen one, as the first generation had very limited memory.

Answer (score 2):

Given the recent developments with symbian and Nokia, I think it might be a decent bet to develop for the Android platform. Given the features you list, either the Google Nexus or any of the Samsung Galaxy series phones would be a good fit. On the android developer website though, google lists the Nexus as the device that one should test all apps on, especially since (IMO, I could be wrong) it is closest to Android-and-nothing-else. Other phones, such as Samsung etc., have Android but also some other APIs on them.

Update: Since you mention a price <= $500, I would suggest the [Google Nexus S](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004USPRM4) or a Samsung Galaxy Pop/Fit etc. That would fit nicely in with your price range.